# convert character to unicode

Tags: python, unicode

This code is working as expected. Only problem is that if there is unicode character, it gets converted to ASCII.

```
with open('test.idx', 'w') as writefile:
    with open('test.dat') as myfile:
        mystr=myfile.read()
        for myword in mystr.split('|'):
            tow=myword, '|', mystr.index(myword)
            print >>writefile, tow

In [74]: !cat test.dat
UTF-8
जनन|1
जन्म देणे
शिक्षण|1
 क्षेत्रातील संशोधनाच्या बाजारीकरणा बाबतीत व्यक्त केलेली 
पूर्व|1
 पगड्यामुळे

In [75]: !cat test.idx
('UTF-8\n\xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xa8', '|', 0)
```

I expect to see unicode instead of escaped code.

Comment: You are seeing the repr output because you are writing tuples, try `print >>writefile, "".join(map(str,tow))` and you will see the correct output

Comment: You created a *tuple*, and like converting any Python container (list, dictionary, etc) to string the contents are represented with the `repr()` output. If that is not the right output, **don't write a raw tuple**.

Comment: Note that you have **UTF-8 data**, not Unicode. The concepts are related, but not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) representation as you are storing the data in a tuple. To match your expected output use str.join:

```
     print >>writefile, "".join(map(str,tow))
```

The output file will contain:

```
UTF-8
जनन|0
1
जन्म देणे
शिक्षण|16
1
 क्षेत्रातील संशोधनाच्या बाजारीकरणा बाबतीत व्यक्त केलेली 
पूर्व|63
1
 पगड्यामुळे|239
```

If you add a `print(tow)` in your code you will see you have tuples.

```
('UTF-8\n\xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xa8', '|', 0)
('1\n\xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xae \xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xa3\xe0\xa5\x87\n\xe0\xa4\xb6\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb7\xe0\xa4\xa3', '|', 16)
('1\n \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb7\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\xb2 \xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa4\x82\xe0\xa4\xb6\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xa7\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x9a\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa4\xbe \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xa3\xe0\xa4\xbe \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\xa4 \xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xa4 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa5\x80 \n\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa5\x82\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb5', '|', 63)
('1\n \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\x97\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa5\x81\xe0\xa4\xb3\xe0\xa5\x87', '|', 239)
```

You also have utf-8 encoded strings not unicode, if you printed the individual elements from tow you would also see the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

You created a tuple:

```
tow=myword, '|', mystr.index(myword)
```

That's not a string object, that's a tuple containing three other objects, two of which are strings, one an integer.

When you then write that tuple to the file, Python has to convert it to a string. Converting any Python container (be that a tuple, a list, a set or a dictionary) will use the `repr()` representation of the contained objects. For strings, that means only printable ASCII characters are allowed and shown, everything else uses escape sequences, most often the `\xhh` form.

If that is not correct output for your usecase, you need to do the string conversion yourself. You could use string formatting:

```
tow = '{}|{}'.format(myword, mystr.index(myword))
```

If you are producing a lot of `|`-separated data, you may want to look at the `csv` module instead to handle the separator and file writing.